# Database Backup issue in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to use mysqldump command for backup my database in Cakephp controller but empty backup file is created. 
i am using this command

$cmd  = 'd: & cd "d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin" & mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > "D:\dump\test.sql"';
    exec($cmd);

Please provide me right solution for backup in cakephp

Thanx

Comment: my problem has been solved

Comment: Then please answer your question with the solution or delete the question if you think it is pointless. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been solved

I am using WAMP And right Code that solved my issue is:

```
$cmd = 'C: & cd "C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin" & mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > "D:\dump\test.sql"'; 

exec($cmd);
```

Thanx!!!